# Why is my || (OR) behaving like an && (and)?

Tags: javascript, validation, email, logical-operators

I am hoping some one can help me here:

I want to validate the user input (email address) on an HTML form. I want both an '@' (at sign) and '.' (period) to present in the user input string.

Here is my code to check if this is the case:

```
function email_checker(id_name){
    var email = document.getElementById(id_name).value;
    if (email.indexOf('@') == -1 && email.indexOf('.') == -1){
    do this code
    }
}
```

The weird thing thing is that it works with an || (logical OR) operator instead of the &&. So, I suppose the question doubles up in that sense;

a) If the (logical OR) works perfectly in this code, why does the (logical AND) not work?

b) Why does the (logical OR) work perfectly - but work as if it were a (logical AND) and not an OR?

(Hope that makes sense :)

I'm obviously missing something. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Provide the exact value of `email` it works that way with. Not reproducible: http://jsfiddle.net/d9EWB/

Answer (score 3):

[DeMorgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) answers the why. If you want to have both, you have to check `has@ and has.`; the failure of this is `not(has@ and has.)`, which breaks down into `not(has@) or not(has.)`, which we can also write as `hasnt@ or hasnt.`. Your current code checks for `hasnt@ and hasnt.`, which is equivalent to `not(has@ or has.)` (i.e. the failure against the rule of "has at least `@` or `.`, not necessarily both" - which is not the rule you wanted).

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to have both `@` and `.`, you should check

```
email.indexOf('@') > -1 && email.indexOf('.') > -1
```

or alternatively the inverse

```
email.indexOf('@') == -1 || email.indexOf('.') == -1
```

Remember that if `indexOf` is `-1`, it means the substring is **not** present.

Answer (score 0):

Your current logic says that if there is neither a `"@"` or a `"."`, then execute your code (in other words, if both are missing).  I think it's your logic that is flawed.  When you use `&&` you are requiring BOTH conditions to be true before it will execute your code.  Since you're testing for `.indexOf() == -1`, that means that both characters have to be missing for it to execute your code which is likely not what you intended.

If you want both a `"@"` or a `"."` to be required in the string, then you can change your `==` to `!==` and still use the `&&` like this to make sure that both required characters are present:

```
function email_checker(id_name){
    var email = document.getElementById(id_name).value;
    // test to make sure neither required character is missing
    if (email.indexOf('@') !== -1 && email.indexOf('.') !== -1){
       // both . and @ are present
       // execute code here
    }
}
```

In a nutshell, you use `&&` if you want BOTH conditions to have to be `true` for the overall result to be `true`.  You were correct in that.  But, you must make sure that the condition you're testing for evaluates to `true` and you were backwards in your logic for that.  When you were testing for `== -1`, you were testing to see if the character was missing so your logic was testing to see if both characters were missing (not one or zero missing, but both).

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [website](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

> $a && $b  And TRUE if both $a and $b are TRUE.
>
> $a || $b  Or  TRUE if either $a or $b is TRUE.

**&& (AND)** will only work if **both** of your condition are satisfied, otherwise only if one condition are satisfied that is **|| (OR)**

Answer (score 0):

You want both conditions to be true for the email to be valid, but you are checking the opposite conditions to catch when it should fail.

You want it to fail if the at is missing *or* if the period is missing, so you want to use the `||` operator between the conditions.